# SQL Query takes time for execution

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, query-optimization

My table having 2 million records. I want to insert data in temp table and use that temp table in my procedure. But for insertion it's taking 30 seconds. Please suggest how to reduce the time?
I cant show actual query. so my query is in this format.

Note: I had already used CTE.

```
;With Tmp_TableName
        as
        (
        SELECT  T1.A, T1.B, T1.C, T1.D, T1.E, T1.F, T1.G , T1.H
        FROM    TableName T1 WITH(NOLOCK)
        WHERE   T1.A = 1
                AND CONVERT( NVarchar, T1.H, 111) <= CONVERT( NVarchar, getdate(), 111)

        )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    Tmp_TableName T1 WITH(NOLOCK);
```

Comment: Is it the select part that is slow or the insert? And why are you comparing dates like this?

Comment: select part taking to much time

Comment: Is this a full query or you doing some other operation before insertion/doing anything.

Comment: @BhavikaZimbar, you can upload your actual execution plan [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the link to your question. An index on `A`, `H` with other columns included should improve performance once you have refactored the `WHERE` clause as suggested to avoid the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend fixing your `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE T1.A = 1 AND
      T1.H < DATEADD(DAY, 1, CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)0
```

This can then take advantage of an index on `TABLE1(A, H)`.

Comment: Thank you. But it's still taking to much time

Answer (score 1):

You can just filter out with `cast()` :

```
WHERE T1.A = 1 AND
      T1.H <= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) -- This assumes `T1.H` has no time. (i.e. 00:00:00);
```

If in your `SELECT` statement has any field which has `varchar/nvarchar(max)` type then it might run to slow, you can exclude it & check further.

However, you didn't included any table structure with indexes so, it is difficult to answer anyone.